# Lambda in VPC - How to setup network

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

## Overview

I have the following network configuration (I simplified it at the cost of correctness a bit to prove my points).

[image]

## My application requirements

- My lambda is an API that needs to be called via http(s). It's setup with a lambda API gateway
- It needs to connect to an RDS in the private subnet
- It needs to do calls to the internet and external APIs

## My problem

1, If I put my lambda in the private subnet

- It will be able to do calls to the internet
- It will **not** be able to be called over the internet <- *This turned out not to be true. The API Gateway is open for calls even though the lambda lives in the private subnet*
- It will be able to connect to the RDS

2, If I put my lambda in the public subnet.

- It will **not** be able to do calls to the internet
- It will be able to be called over the internet
- It will be able to connect to the RDS

3, If I do not put my lambda in the VPC it cannot connect to the RDS.

- It will be able to do calls to the internet
- It will be able to be called over the internet
- It will **not** be able to connect to the RDS

## Other

I am using terraform to setup my infrastructure so I prefer answers and examples using terraform, but of course all input is welcome.

Comment: Your diagram looks fine, though your subsequent descriptions are incorrect as Mark B. has indicated. If this is genuinely how your system looks, what problem are you having with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I put my lambda in the private subnet,
>
> - It will **not** be able to be called over the internet

This is incorrect. The Lambda function never sits idle listening for requests. An AWS Lambda function itself never receives incoming network traffic directly. The Lambda function is a piece of code that is invoked with an event payload. You could block all inbound network connections to your Lambda function via the attached security group, and you will still be able to invoke the Lambda function without issue, because the Lambda function never receives inbound network requests directly.

The public AWS API, or your API Gateway, are the services that are available on the public Internet, listening for network requests. Those services construct an event payload from those requests, and then invoke your Lambda function with that event payload.

Deploying your Lambda function into a private subnet is the correct configuration here. AWS API Gateway will be able to receive public network requests, and create invocations of your Lambda function that will run in your private subnet.

Comment: Ok, so you are completely right. I was somehow confusing myself when testing. So what got me stubled was that something made my API gateway not working when I tested for http calls when running my lambda in the private subnet. 

So yes: API gateway DOES work even though the lambda itself is running in a private subnet.